# jquery replace HTML div value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am forming the div dynamically on document load like below. I have a ajax call and on response fro the AJAXcall I want to replace the value **'right'** with the value from the AJAX call using `jQuery`.

Basically I want to replace the value for the text div mentioned below once AJAX has the success data.

```
var beginContainer = '<div class="container">';
var endDiv = '</div>';
var beginInner = '<div class="inner">';
var text = '<div class="text" id=3 style="color:#0000FF" align ="center">';
var append = beginContainer + beginInner + text + 'Number of sensors' + endDiv + text + '10cents/sensor' + endDiv + endDiv + beginInner + text +'right'+endDiv +endDiv;

$('#content').append(append);  

var beginContainer = '<div class="container">';
var endDiv = '</div>';
var beginInner = '<div class="inner">';
var text = '<div class="text" id=4 style="color:#0000FF" align ="center" value="kkk">';
var append = beginContainer + beginInner + text + 'Total Bill' + endDiv + text + 'Month-to-Month' + endDiv + endDiv + beginInner + text +'right'+endDiv +endDiv;

$('#content').append(append);
```

Comment: Where's the `AJAX` call?

Comment: Anyway... The easiest way is to wrap the text on a `span` and give this element an `ID`. So you can refer to it by its `ID` later.

Comment: FYI, you have `id=3` in `text` variable's div, and in the `append` variable, you are using `text` multiple times. This will create multiple elements with the same id, which is not proper HTML and is considered a very bad practice. I think you should consider fixing this and perhaps refactor the code to make it easier to spot before working on the AJAX or you'll be in for a lot more headache down the line.

Comment: I can get rid off the id tag on text. I am not using it any way.

Comment: The `div` element doesn't have an attribute `value`. Also, the use of the attribute `align` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `span` tag, something like:

```
var append = beginContainer + beginInner 
    + text + 'Number of sensors' + endDiv + text 
    + '10cents/sensor' + endDiv + endDiv + beginInner 
    + text + '<span id="yourSpan">right</span>' 
    + endDiv + endDiv;
```

So you can use reference it by:

```
$("#yourSpan").html("ajaxResult");
```

Answer (score -2):

use this for your ajax call:

```
$.ajax("URL.com",function(e){
  $("#wherever").html(e);
});
```

Comment: This will replace the whole content of the selected element.

Comment: he said "i want to replace the value for the text div mentioned below once ajax has the success data", so if you run: 

$(".text").html(e);

Comment: The OP wants to replace a specific word that's part of the element's content, not its entire content. Read the question again. _I want replace the value **'right'** with the value from the AJAX call_